# Briecked AVR. Do I set extended fuse?

Tags: avr, atmega, avrdude

I've uploaded program to ATmega88p, then executed avrdude with
`-U lfuse:w:0x63:m -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m -U efuse:w:0xFF:m`
to set clock to 128kHz according to http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/
The proggram executed fine, but then I wanted to execute avrdude with
`-U lfuse:w:0x7F:m -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m -U efuse:w:0xFF:m`
to set the clock back to 8MHz, but I've received error **rc=-1**.
When I used avrdude with **-F** to check the signature, I've received `0xdc57df`, wchih looks random.
Prevously I did same thing (with diffrent h and l fuses values) to ATmega8, and it worked just fine afterwards.
I wanted to know if I should set extended fuse in the future or Is the high and low one enough in most cases?

Comment: You should add a switch to lower avrdude SPI clock frequency to very low value. It seems you programmed CKDIV8 fuse so that actual CPU frequency is 128kHz/8 = 16 kHz and programming SPI clock should not be higher than 4 kHz. See -i/-B switches depend on your programmer hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISP clock speed should be at most 1/4 of the CPU frequency. Therefore if the CPU runs at 128kHz, programming speed should be less than 32kHz. I.e. one bit clock period should be at least 32 microseconds or more.

Try to pass `-B 64` option in the avrdude command line. (full list of options is [here](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions))

Answer (score 0):

As ReAl noted, the issue is in something different. The fuses are set all right, but can't be changed because the programer can't work this slow. After changing avrdude parameters it worked.